# Protect images download theory

Tags: javascript, html, image, security

I am a full-time developer but am building a site for my photography hobby. I dont want people to download my images and besides the usual procedures (disable right click, block hotlinks to my images etc.) i was thinking about a solution which would work 99% of the time.

The idea was to render images in a canvas or load it as a binary file or similar.

How would be performance compared to standard src linking?

And are there better solutions to my problem?

Comment: You could digitally watermark the images?

Comment: people can just take a screenshot

Comment: @NeilMunro - True, but a watermark doesn't stop people from taking the image, it just makes it harder to claim it as their work.

Comment: Even if you render it to a canvas people you still need to send the image to the client in some way and when you do that it can be retrieved.

Comment: They could still screenshot your images. Watermarking them would be a solution, but as a fellow photography hobbyist, I think that's a pitty. I honestly don't care if people download my photographs from my photobook (http://pierreespenan.com/photobook/) , especially since I am not a pro.

Comment: Like others said, the moment someone has information to render an image, they can save it if they want to. People who are not very IT savvy usually have friends that are. The one and only way for you to stop someone from taking the image is simply not to show it at all. This isn't the answer you want to hear, but that's how it is. I won't try to preach and moralize about what you should do, but just bear in mind that it's not  worth your time coming up with various ways of protection if there's a guy like me who can go around it in mere seconds.

Comment: _I honestly don't care if people download my photographs_ - That doesn't really help the OP.

Comment: @BSMP: True. It was just a way of saying that maybe OP shouldn't be so worried about his pics being downloaded :)

Comment: Watermarks are ugly. And making them small can mean you can crop or copy it out... Screenshots are not that much a problem, as you then dont have full resolutions.
What about the binary inline src option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a picture is displayed on someone's screen, there is no way you can avoid them to save it on their computer (even if you disable everything).

Trying to obfuscate the images will only result in a loss of time, performance, and could make your website much less user-friendly.

Comment: I accept this because it matches what people in the comments think. Still i had loved an answer about that binary inline src option...